# check box code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
<script>
function edit(em) {
    var ch = em.value;

    var ed = $("td.td" + ch).value;
    if ($(ed).is(: checked)) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
   
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="25" onclick="edit(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" value="26" onclick="edit(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" value="27" onclick="edit(this)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td25" value="25"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
            <td class="td26" value="26"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
            <td class="td27" value="27"><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what's not working here ?

Comment: i want that if i click on which check box to hide that under given edit link

Comment: `$("td.td" + ch).value;` `td` does not have value. `$(this).show()` - `this` here means checkbox. Which is already shown.

Comment: Which elements are you trying to show/hide? `Checkbox`, `td` or `a`?

Comment: i am trying td tag...

Answer (score 1):

here is a bug:

```
if($(ed).is(:checked))...
```

shoul be:

```
if($(ed).is(':checked'))...
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is what you are trying to do.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 
  var ch = this.value;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(".td" + ch).hide();
      }
     else
       {
         $(".td" + ch).show();
       }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="25" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="26" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="27" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td25" value="25"><a href="#">Edit25</a></td>
            <td class="td26" value="26"><a href="#">Edit26</a></td>
            <td class="td27" value="27"><a href="#">Edit27</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you're trying to do:

```
function edit(em) {
    var ch = em.value;

    var ed = $("td.td" + ch);
    if ($(em).is(':checked')) {
        ed.show();
    } else {
        ed.hide();
    }
}
```

If that's what you're trying to achieve, then here are things you weren't doing right:

- As @yangguang said, you were missing quotes for checked `(':checked')`
- You wanted to take `td` not its value.
- You were checking whether `td` (or its value) is `checked` which
  instead you should have done it for the `checkbox`.
- `$(this)` refers to the checkbox, but you wanted to show/hide the `td`